# http.client.BadStatusLine: '' when attempting app-only twitter oauth with python3

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I am trying to create a script that will process `Twitter` streams.  Unfortunately, the OAuth process has stymied me.  Adopting some code I found on the internet, I receive a blank response from https://api.twitter.com/oauth/token.  In order to better understand the process, I am trying to do this without special modules.  Here is my code, what am missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
import http.client
import urllib
import base64

CONSUMER_KEY = 'yadayadayada'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'I am really tired today'

encoded_CONSUMER_KEY = urllib.parse.quote(CONSUMER_KEY)
encoded_CONSUMER_SECRET = urllib.parse.quote(CONSUMER_SECRET)
concat_consumer_url = encoded_CONSUMER_KEY + ':' + encoded_CONSUMER_SECRET


host = 'api.twitter.com'
url = '/oauth2/token/'
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'})
req = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host, timeout = 100)
req.set_debuglevel(1)
req.putrequest("POST", url)
req.putheader("Host", host)
req.putheader("User-Agent", "My Twitter 1.1")
req.putheader("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode(b'concat_consumer_url'))
req.putheader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
req.putheader("Content-Length", "29")
req.putheader("Accept-Encoding", "identity")
req.endheaders()

req.send(b'params')

resp = req.getresponse()


print ("{} {}".format(resp.status, resp.reason))
```

Error message:

```
C:\Python33>app_only_test_klug.py
Traceback <most recent call last>:
    File "C:\Python33\app_only_test_klug.py", line 31, in <module>
        resp = req.getresponse()
    File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1131, in getresponse
        response.being()
    File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 354, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 324, in _read_status
        raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

After some more tinkering, I believe that the issue lies with my base64 encoding:

req.putheader("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode(b'concat_consumer_url'))

When I decode the resulting encoding of the above, I get "b'concat_consumer_url'" rather than a concatenation of the encoded_CONSUMER_KEY and encoded_CONSUMER_SECRET combined around a colon.  How do I get the base64 to b64encode the value that concat_comsumer_url represents rather than the string "concat_consumer_url" so that I can move forward?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is there as well--you should just pass the variable to the encoding function, rather than the name of the variable as bytes, like this:

```
req.putheader("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode(concat_consumer_url))
```

Try it again with that change.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked for the formatting but the response is still coming up blank.